# Kafka Connect: Reading "Connect.offsets" in standalone mode to get the last processed offset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am implementing a Kafka Source Connector. In standalone mode I see the latest processed offsets are stored in /tmp/connect.offsets file. I want to read this and in the next run start the processing from this offset. I am trying to use context.offsetStorageReader() method offset or offsets to read this information.

However method offset has the following signature : https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/OffsetStorageReader.html

> offset
>
> `<T> java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> offset​(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,T> partition)`
>
> Get the offset for the specified partition. If the data isn't already available locally, this gets it from the backing store, which may require some network round trips.
>   Parameters:
>
> partition - object uniquely identifying the partition of data
>
> Returns:
>   object uniquely identifying the offset in the partition of data

I am not sure what needs to be supplied to the parameter partions here to get the offset in the output map. I see no examples to read from connect.offsets In this file I see the correct offsets for my topic/partition but what is parameter I need to pass to the OffsetStorageReader offset method to get the output.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Okay there is a straightforward way to do this. I feel silly for not figuring this out earlier. context.offsetStorageReader().offset() needs a parameter. This parameter can be Collections.singletonMap("PARTITION", partitionID)  partitionID is the string ID of the partition

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the file. Standalone and distributed mode should work the exact same way

Comment: thanks  cricket_007 . I agree. I was trying this out standalone mode before I work on distributed mode next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

context.offsetStorageReader().offset() needs a parameter. This parameter can be Collections.singletonMap("PARTITION", partitionID)

partitionID is the string ID of the partition. Below worked for me,

```
context.offsetStorageReader().offset(Collections.singletonMap("PARTITION", partitionID))
```